# Before insert trigger (PL/SQL) does not fire in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a simple trigger defined for the Jobs table in HR sample database from Oracle. I am testing it inside Oracle SQL Developer.

```
set serveroutput on;
create or replace trigger insertjob
 before insert on jobs
  begin 
    dbms_output.put_line(' Hello!');
    end;
```

Then I insert a row on purpose to fail, such as
`INSERT INTO jobs(job_id, job_title, min_salary, max_salary) VALUES('IT_TEST', 6000, 12000);` 
The console output is:

```
INSERT INTO jobs(job_id, job_title, min_salary, max_salary) VALUES('IT_TEST', 6000, 12000)
Error at Command Line : 26 Column : 61
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values
00947. 00000 -  "not enough values"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

But no firing of the trigger before the insert. I was expecting to see the message "Hello!" just before the error because that trigger should fire regardless of the success or failure of the insert operation, but that did not happened!
Anyone knows why?

Best regards,
Sorin

Comment: The trigger won't fire until the insert actually executes - and you aren't getting to that point because the parser is throwing that error. Oracle parses the statement and only executes it if it is valid.

Comment: you can maybe use instead of trigger for your case

Comment: Instead of isn't used only for views, and not for tables?

Answer (score 0):

You are using:

```sql
INSERT INTO jobs(
  job_id,    job_title, min_salary, max_salary
)VALUES(
  'IT_TEST', 6000,      12000       -- nothing for the 4th column
);
```

You have specified that you are `INSERT`ing into 4 columns but you have only provided 3 values. Your query is not syntactically valid so it is not being executed. There is nothing wrong with your trigger - it just isn't running because your `INSERT` statement is invalid and is not being executed so nothing is triggering the `TRIGGER`.

To fix it, provide a 4th value to the `INSERT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO jobs(
  job_id,  job_title, min_salary, max_salary
)VALUES(
  'job_id', 'IT_TEST', 6000,       12000
);
```

or else use `DEFAULT` if you want the default value to be inserted:

```sql
INSERT INTO jobs(
  job_id,  job_title, min_salary, max_salary
)VALUES(
  DEFAULT, 'IT_TEST', 6000,       12000
);
```

When your query is syntactically valid then the SQL engine will execute it and the trigger will trigger.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/T1BJv0iM)